# When does Oracle sql exclusively lock a row in an update statement?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to see whether I can use database lock to deal with race conditions.  For example

```
CREATE TABLE ORDER
(
    T1_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    AMT NUMBER,
    STATUS1 CHAR(1),
    STATUS2 CHAR(1),
    UPDATED_BY VARCHAR(25)
);

insert into order values (order_seq.nextval, 1, 'N', 'N', 'U0');
```

Later two users can update the order record at the same time.  Requirement is that only one can proceed while the other should NOT. We can certainly use a distributed lock manager (DLM) to do this but I figure database lock may be more efficient.

> User 1:

```
update T1 set status1='Y', updated_by='U1' where status1='N';
```

> User 2:

```
update T1 set status2='Y', updated_by='U2' where status1='N';
```

Two users are doing these at the same time.  Ideally only one should be allowed to proceed.  I played using Sql Plus and also wrote a little java test program letting two threads do these simultaneously.  I got the same result.  Let's say User 1 got the DB row lock first.  It returns 1 row updated.  The second session will be blocked waiting for the row lock before the 1st session commits or rollbacks.  The question is REALLY this:

Update with a where clause seems like two operations: first it will do an implicit select based on the where clause to pick the row that will be updated. Since Oracle only supports READ COMMITTED isolation level, I expect both UPDATE statements will pick the single record in the DB.  As a result, I expected both UPDATE statement will eventually return "1 row updated" although one will wait till the other transaction commits.  HOWEVER  that's not what I saw.  The second UPDATE returns "0 row updated" after the first commits.  I feel that Oracle actually runs the where clause AGAIN after the first session commits, which results in "0 row updated" result.

This is strange to me.  I thought I would run into the classical "lost update" phenomenon.

can somebody please explain what's going on here?  Thanks very much!

Comment: Sorry I messed up table names.  Assume table order and T1 as same

Comment: "*I feel that Oracle runs the where clause again*" - that's precisely what happens. See the manual for details: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/consist.htm#GUID-E6FB4581-CD65-4C18-AFDD-ACB3243238D3__GUID-6F6A0A32-87B1-4F60-A3A4-C5EDBB157F82

Comment: Excuse me but where does Oracle document say the where clause will be executed twice?  My experiment result indicates so but I can't find anything in the Oracle document